# DependencyProperty - How to set a step change in value?

Tags: wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I created a DependencyProperty  for UserControl that should be in the range of -2 .. 2

When rotating the mouse scroll wheel in the properties window.
The property value changes by one. And I want to value changed by 0.1
How do I set a step change in DependencyProperty? 
I work with properties in XAML editor.

```
 public double Value
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(BarValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BarValueProperty, value); }
        }


        public static readonly DependencyProperty BarValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(double), typeof(MeterBar), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
```

Answer (score 0):

When adding the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` options into the definition of a `DependencyProperty`, there is an option to provide a `CoerceValueCallback` handler. You can change the incomming values in this handler. For complete details, please see the [Dependency Property Callbacks and Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795.aspx) page on MSDN. From the linked page:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentReadingProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
    "CurrentReading",
    typeof(double),
    typeof(Gauge),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        Double.NaN,
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure,
        new PropertyChangedCallback(OnCurrentReadingChanged),
        new CoerceValueCallback(CoerceCurrentReading)
    ),
    new ValidateValueCallback(IsValidReading)
);
public double CurrentReading
{
  get { return (double)GetValue(CurrentReadingProperty); }
  set { SetValue(CurrentReadingProperty, value); }
}

...

private static object CoerceCurrentReading(DependencyObject d, object value)
{
    // Do whatever calculation to update your value you need to here
    Gauge g = (Gauge)d;
    double current = (double)value;
    if (current
            <g.MinReading) current = g.MinReading;
    if (current >g.MaxReading) current = g.MaxReading;
    return current;
}
```

Comment: As I understand it is to control the range of values.
But I need to control the step change from the settings window.